# How a4j poll not to refresh images in Chrome

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I've many nested `<ui:repeat>`tags and I must to update data inside in regular periods. Therefore I use a4j:poll. But to update data inside nested `<ui:repeat>` tags I must refresh the `<div id="div1">` tag before first (root) `<ui:repeat>` tag. My problem is that in nested '' tags there are images that don't change and after invoke each action (`<a4j:poll action="#{bean.update} render="div1"/>`), these pictures are reloaded. In IE and Firefox there isn't a problem, the pictures and divs are caching and only the data changes. In Chrome all divs and images nested in `<div id="div1">` are reloaded. Can I tell the a4j:poll to not reload images width explicit ids or to make Chrome to cache them with JavaScript or something else? For example :

```
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="div1">  
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.someListData}" var="data">
            <ui:repeat value="..." var="...">
                ... 
                <img id="mustNotBeReloaded"/>
                <h:outputText id="mustBeReloaded"/>
                ...               
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:poll action="#{bean.update}" render="div1"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Which response headers are on the image requests?

Comment: I use `<h:graphicImage value="images/#{bean.imgId}"/>`, where imgId is the identifier of the image (type long) and I've a servlet with mapping `/images/*` that takes the image from DB.

Comment: And here is the response header on image request:                   Content-Length:102992
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 05 Dec 2011 10:12:39 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this with setting the response header on image request :

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + 100000);
```